# Tk Tablelist, how to make red border in a tablelist cell

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

```
package require Tk
package require Tablelist


tablelist::addOakleyCombobox 
    ::tablelist::tablelist .tbl \
            -columns "0 A center 0 B center 0 C center" \
            -stretch all \
            -showseparators 1 

pack .tbl -side top -fill both -expand yes

.tbl insert end ""

proc createWindow {tbl row col w} {
    button $w -text OK
}

.tbl cellconfigure 0,1 -window createWindow
```

How to make a red border around OK button. I want it to be expanded in whole cell. Something like this 
[image]

Button isn't necessary. Red border is needed to highlight errors in cells.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to put the button (or whatever contained widget you want) inside a `frame` widget that you stick to the walls of the cell. You then make the frame show the red border by configuring it to have `-highlightthickness 1 -highlightbackground red -highlightcolor red`, which will put a solid red 1-pixel-wide border on the frame (frames default to having an invisible focus highlight ring, but we repurpose it here; you can't use a `-relief solid` standard border because those use a fixed color). You might also need to adjust the padding on the contained widget.

I *think* you make a widget expand within its tablelist cell by specifying `-stretchwindow 1` as an option to the `cellconfigure` option, but I've not tried that. (The [documentation](http://www.nemethi.de/tablelist/tablelistWidget.html#cell_stretchwindow) is slightly unspecific about this in a curiously detailed way; you might need to ask the author of tablelist if you're having problems getting it to work.)

Comment: Thanks for reply but I use tablelist version 4.8 and it hasn't -stretchwindow cell configuration option. Is there any other way for expanding window in cell? I think in createWindow proc $w frame is already packed, how can I pack it manually?